# Why the spacing of header in Microsoft Word behave differently?

Tags: microsoft-word

I create a heading and the settings are below:

> Font: (Asian) +Headings Asian (SimSun), (Default) Times New Roman, Bold, English (United Kingdom), Centered
>       Line spacing:  single, Space
>       Before:  4 line
>       After:  4 line, Widow/Orphan control, Page break before, Level 1, Outline numbered + Level: 1 + Numbering Style: 1, 2, 3, … + Start at: 1 + Alignment: Left + Aligned at:  0" + Indent at:  0.25", Style: Linked, Automatically update, Show in the Styles gallery, Priority: 10
>       Following style: Body

[image: This is what I'm supposed to get.]
**This is what I'm supposed to get.**

But when I applied the same heading to chapter 2 it behave differently.

[image: This behaves differently]
**This behaves differently**

Why is the spacing before the heading missing?

Comment: It might be due to the Page Break before setting. What happens if you change the style to exclude that? Do you get the space then?

Comment: What version of Word do you use? How Word handles space before is a rather complex problem. For example for Word 2007 similar (opposite) problem is described here: https://wordribbon.tips.net/T008254_Eliminating_Before_Spacing_at_the_Top_of_a_Page.html - there is a number of factors that affect space before.

Comment: @Twisty u are correct. Page Break before cause this behaviour. But what can I do if I need a page break?

Comment: @endrju I am using Microsoft Office 365.

Comment: @SamTew Then in fact you use Word 2016. I have only Word 2010, so I cannot test this, but the author of a question https://superuser.com/questions/1082164/microsoft-word-2016-no-top-spacing-on-pagebreak wrote that using a section break is a workaround. Works for me in 2010.